# Neural net example not working

Tags: bugs, machine-learning, neural-networks

**Bug introduced in 11.0.0 and fixed via paclet update**

---

The Wolfram Mathematica site provides [this example](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/neural-networks/multi-task-learning.html?product=mathematica).

I have copied and pasted into a notebook. The resource is reached and correctly sampled.

However, the following does not run.

```
convnet = 
 NetChain[{ConvolutionLayer[20, {5, 5}], ElementwiseLayer[Ramp], 
   PoolingLayer[{2, 2}, {2, 2}], ConvolutionLayer[50, {5, 5}], 
   ElementwiseLayer[Ramp], PoolingLayer[{2, 2}, {2, 2}], 
   FlattenLayer[], DotPlusLayer[500], ElementwiseLayer[Ramp]}, 
  "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {32, 32}}]]
```

The following error is produced:

[image]

Apologies for the size.

Have other users experience the same error?

(I am on Windows 10).

Comment: I have contacted Technical Support. Will update if and when a reply.

Comment: I have the same error - Windows 7

Comment: It runs fine - Mma 11.0.0 Win7

Comment: Same error. (Using version 11.0.0 under Win 10, too.)

Comment: Same problem with [this example](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/neural-networks/digit-classification.html?product=mathematica). I have not tried other ones.

Comment: Thank you everyone. Will update with any information from Wolfram TS. Appreciate any other advice. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is actually a bug in a separate paclet that corrupts kernel state. It happens to show up here in neural networks. It has been fixed and a patch issued, your local install should acquire the update in time, but you should be able to force an update by running `PacletUpdate["Streaming"]`.

In the meantime (or if that doesn't work for you), you can avoid this issue by running `NetChain;` on a fresh kernel (i.e. Quit) before running the example code.

Comment: thank you very much for answer.

Comment: Did this issue first appear in 11.0.0? I wish to add an appropriate bugs header, per site convention.